# NullPointerException in Java Android App MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

HELP please this is just a simple android app I am developing, it's meant to play a sound every time you click the button....it works when I click the button at a slow pace, but always crashes if I click the button at a fast pace due to a runtime error - NullPointerException!.....I don't know what I am doing wrong.

THIS IS MY CODE

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    e.setOnClickListener(this);    

}

public void onClick(View v){

    if(v.getId()==R.id.imageButton1){
    final MediaPlayer i = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.sound);
    i.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            i.release();                    
        }
    });

    i.start();  
    }       

}
```

}

Comment: this line -> i.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

Comment: Please read the documentation before you try to use it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only a guess but in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you will find the following

> `public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)`
>   ...
>   Returns a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

This means you should make sure that the line

```
final MediaPlayer i = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.sound);
```

does not return a `null`.

**Edit:**

Im really not sure how to handle the situation if `create(Context context, int resid)` is failing. But you have to do, because it is even from the documentation very clear that it can happen.

To be sure this is really the problem just ignore this case and return from your handler.
For example...

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1)
    {
        final MediaPlayer i = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.sound);

        if (i != null)
        {
            ...

            i.start();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but any ideas on how I can do that?...Cause i'm pretty much out of ideas on what to do....Thanks again!

Comment: Im really not sure how to handle the situation if `create(Context context, int resid)` is failing. Its your decision. I have edited my answer.

Comment: By the way, maybe its not necessary to create a new `MediaPlayer` instance in any new call to your handler.

Comment: Thanks, I have previously tried the if (i != null) statement, it deals with the nullPointerException error but creates a new error 'Unable to create media player' which stops the program from outputting a sound after a couple of clicks....maybe I should go through the Android MediaPlayer documentation for the fourth time again and see if there's anything I'm missing

Comment: what if my video is not in the raw folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way....

```
public class Blah extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle b)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);

      mp = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.match);
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            i.release();                    
        }
    });

      e.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   mp.seekTo(0);
                       mp.start();

            }
        });
   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try your method and get back to you now

Comment: Thanks again, I've just tried your method, it solves the NullPointerException error but creates a new error called - 'IllegalStateException' at the mp.seekTo(0) line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

my solution was to re-encode the mp3 files with the LAME mp3 encoder

You can use this program: http://www.freac.org/index.php/en/downloads-mainmenu-33

apparently android is quite picky about mp3 codecs