# MediaPlayer crashes the activity when I use the start() method on an activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have tried many ways to do make music play at the menu screen (first activity). I have tried this which results in an app crash that never opens:

```
Mediaplayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Play music at the menu screen (main activity)
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menumusic);
    mp.start();
}
```

and I have tried this which prevents a crash at the start but does not play any music:

```
Mediaplayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Play music at the menu screen (main activity)
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.menumusic);
    mp.start();
}
```

crash log for first one:

```
    08-19 13:20:03.619  12759-12759/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-19 13:20:03.620  12759-12759/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-19 13:20:03.784  12759-12773/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_2
08-19 13:20:04.533  12780-12780/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-19 13:20:04.535  12780-12780/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-19 13:20:05.589    931-12814/? E/GenericSource﹕ Failed to init from data source!
08-19 13:20:05.592  12794-12810/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
08-19 13:20:05.594  12794-12794/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jason.dodge, PID: 12794
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jason.dodge/com.example.jason.dodge.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.jason.dodge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

crash log for second one:

```
08-19 13:24:17.961  13075-13082/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-19 13:24:18.095  13075-13089/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
08-19 13:24:18.098  13075-13075/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 1
08-19 13:24:18.098  13075-13075/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
08-19 13:24:18.100  13075-13075/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
08-19 13:24:18.202  13075-13075/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

log while doing mp.prepare() surrounded with a try/catch after the mp.create(this,R.raw.menumusic); line

```
08-19 13:37:58.455  18212-18226/com.example.jason.dodge E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
08-19 13:37:58.456  18212-18212/com.example.jason.dodge E/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync called in state 1
08-19 13:37:58.456  18212-18212/com.example.jason.dodge E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jason.dodge, PID: 18212
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jason.dodge/com.example.jason.dodge.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1135)
            at com.example.jason.dodge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

it still says caused by illegal state. thought the preparing of it would fix that so it wouldn't start until the prepared state

Comment: show us your crash logs

Comment: Could  you provide your logcat, please?

Comment: stackoverlow.com should be renamed to showcrashlogs.com, perhaps that would help.

Comment: sorry, new to this.... will add a comment with it in a second
**edit:** how do I view the log? When I run it, it will show for a split second then go away

Comment: I believe your problem is trying to use the MediaPlayer on the UI thread. Consider running it in the background.

Comment: Jason, no problem but don't add a comment. Use the "edit" button below the tags and add the stacktrace to your post. Most likely, creation is failing due to incompatible types or something similar. If so, you will be getting a `NPE` on `mp.start()` so you will need to research why it would return null. @jasonwarford No, it can be run on the Main thread

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States), you can only start a media player when it is in state `Prepared`. Well, other states too, but a fresh media player needs to be prepared, you can register an `OnPreparedListener` to get notified about it.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg good point, but note you can call `prepare` synchronously in this case "For files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks until MediaPlayer is ready for playback" That goes for resources too.

Comment: What type of file is the menumusic resource?

Comment: @weston hmm, would one one call `prepare` synchronously even in `onCreate` on the *UiThread*?

Comment: the menumuisc was a .mp3 file. that didn't work (same results as above) and i renamed it to be .ogg and opened it in VLC player to make sure it wasn't corrupted and the song played normally. So right now its with the .ogg extension. I am trying to do mp.prepare() after i create the mediaplayer and i surrounded it with a try/catch but that won't load thea app at all, (instant crash) see the OP for that log

Comment: Yes renaming won't have an effect. VLC player is probably ignoring the extension.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg yes that's how I interpret the docs. It's going to be very quick to prepare. If it turned out not to be, then I'd look at prepareasync

Comment: According to the MediaPlayer documentation you should be doing a null check on the MediaPlayer instance. It says that it can come back as null.  Can you try another .mp3 file? It is likely an issue with the mp3 encoding.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17971572/433234