# I can't get the mediaplayer working in android studio

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player

I'm trying to get some sound in my app, but I can't get the mediaplayer working! I got some errors like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

with the following code:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.NAMEOFSOUND);
}

protected void playBtnClicked(){
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

It just doesn't work, whatever I do ... Does someone got some tips/Can someone help me out? The ''NAMEOFSOUND'' is a .mp3 file, I don't know if it even matters? Thank you!

SOLVED: I just solved it by coverting the file with a converter. Just changing the name+.mp3 didn't solve it; [NullPointerException in Java Android App MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332603/nullpointerexception-in-java-android-app-mediaplayer/17971572#17971572) , comment of Berty did the trick!

Comment: .mav is not an audio file format. Did you mean .wav?

Comment: Instead of just adding these "Edit:" lines, clean up your question and remove the outdated pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [supported Media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) .mav is not supported by android. you should convert it to mp3 or any of the supported file formats

Comment: I converted the file to .mp3, but I still got the same problem?